# Group JQuery Selector by element type

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

When using the .each function with JQuery like below is there anyway to automatically group the results by type to save some time;

```
$(selector).each(function () {
      //do stuff here for each found
});
```

The above will obviously go through each found element one by one but with the logic within my code I'm just detecting what field type the field is and I would action each field type to do the same thing. I'm just trying to save doing all the logic for the same field type over and over again.

To detail a little more, I have a value and it needs to go into may different fields types. Simple text fields are fine as they're just insert in using `.val()` but for other default and custom fields that I have such as picklists and multi-select boxes I need to do some logic around the value for these fields so the appropriate values are set, but not all these type fields don't exist so don't want to do the necessary logic beforehand if those fields don't actually exist. So if I had 50 picklist fields I would obviously only want to do that logic once and set the values for all picklist fields to this value(s) that the logic had set. I just thought they're might be a simple method of JQuery that I'm missing here?!

Comment: explain what you are looking for

Comment: Behind the screen the logic will probably be done for each element anyway, so what time are you trying to save? Is your code actually too slow?

Comment: if the fields do not exist, then the code will not run for them. It only gets applied on found DOM elements.

Comment: Just put some more info at the bottom if that helps?!

Answer (score 0):

You can do some manual testing and run your code a different way

```
var all = $(selector),
    text = all.filter('[type="text"]'),
    select = all.filter('select');

text.val(someValue);
if (select.length){ // select elements exist
   // do logic and apply to all
   select.val(selectSpecificValue);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Gaby, think I've just overthought the whole scenario!